# 550 sender rejected - sender domain has no MX/A record. Different IP for MX & A Records

Tags: domain, wordpress, email-bounces

I have a website that has different hosting for website and email. I host the website and another company hosts the email and handle the domain.

This is how the domain is set up: *(The domain name & IP are masked for privacy purpose)*

```
Record                  Type    TTL     Content
<domain>.com.au         A       1 hour  180.235.xxx.xx
<domain>.com.au         MX      1 hour  mail.<domain>.com.au
<domain>.com.au         A       1 hour  125.255.xx.xx
<domain>.com.au         NS      1 hour  ns1.planetdomain.com
<domain>.com.au         NS      1 hour  ns2.planetdomain.com
<domain>.com.au         SOA     1 hour  ....
blog.<domain>.com.au    A       1 hour  180.235.xxx.xx
www.<domain>.com.au     A       1 hour  180.235.xxx.xx
```

The website uses WordPress and occassionaly send enquiries to the company. However there are times that this error message will come up:

```
Spurlingtamworth@bestdressedmen.com.au
host mx1.pm.telstra.com [203.147.175.1]
SMTP error from remote mail server after MAIL FROM:<spurling@vps1.preschem.com> SIZE=2300:
550 5.1.0 <spurling@vps1.preschem.com> sender rejected - sender domain has no MX/A record
```

I understand that the MX records are pointing to different IP Address. I don't know how, but WordPress seems to be able to send email just fine despite having different IP Address for the MX Records. However for some addresses, the emails keep bouncing back.

**How do I fix this issue? Do I have to fix this from the webhosting side or from domain side?**

I have set the MX Entries in cPanel as **Remote Mail Exchanger**. So emails will go to the email hosting instead.

Comment: Looks like this is happening from a script on your server and the sending address is being translated to spurling@vps1.preschem.com when it should be Spurlingtamworth@bestdressedmen.com.au. Check your postfix configuration especially /etc/postfix/main.cf

Comment: [Administration panels are off topic](http://serverfault.com/help/on-topic). [Even the presence of an administration panel on a system,](http://meta.serverfault.com/q/6538/118258) because they [take over the systems in strange and non-standard ways, making it difficult or even impossible for actual system administrators to manage the servers normally](http://meta.serverfault.com/a/3924/118258), and tend to indicate low-quality questions from *users* with insufficient knowledge for this site.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The message is quite right: Your sender's domain hasn't got either an MX or A record.

```
$ host vps1.preschem.com
Host vps1.preschem.com not found: 3(NXDOMAIN)
```

According to [RFC 5321 section 2.3.5](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5321#section-2.3.5) the [sender domain must be valid and resolvable](https://serverfault.com/a/671981/126632). If not, any mail server can reject the mail.

You fix the issue by giving it an appropriate address record or records.

Comment: The vps1.preschem.com is the given name from my VPS hosting provider. If I add A record to it, will it cause anything else? And do I put the email hosting IP Address or the web hosting IP Address? Sorry I'm a bit blurred with this.

Comment: You don't have to keep their name, and if it isn't valid, you should not do. You can actually name your server with a valid name (in your domain) and give that name the correct A record.

Answer (score 2):

Some mail servers, to mitigate spam, require that the sender's domain resolves to a proper dns 'A' record and in extreme cases to an 'MX' record. Doing `dig` on vps1.preschem.com for 'A' or 'MX' records does not return anything.

Solution - Add `A` record for vps1.preschem.com

```
root@svm1010:/var/tmp# dig vps1.preschem.com MX +short
root@svm1010:/var/tmp# dig vps1.preschem.com +short
root@svm1010:/var/tmp#
```

Comment: If I add A records to vps1.preschem.com, will it cause anything else?

Comment: No, that should not cause any problem.

Answer (score 0):

The error generated here is because the sender address is invalid and the Telstra server thinks you're spam.

The sender address is spurling@vps1.preschem.com. The Telstra server is looking up the vps1.preschem.com domain and finding no MX or A record and therefore noone can send email to that address. Change the sender address to something valid (or at least a valid domain name) and these particular errors should disappear.